# PowerShell script works perfectly but takes 8+ hours to run

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that goes out and grabs a config file from a server, parses some data, and then pings devices to see if they are online or offline. It works 100% as expected - but it is taking over 8 hours to run.  I am just wondering if there is something in my logic that is causing this to happen.  I do realize that it could be related to other issues, but I wanted to rule this out.  Can anyone see a fault in the logic that would be causing it to take longer, i.e. if it's getting stuck in a loop of some sort, etc.?

Here is my code:

```
$logfile = "D:\Logs\MPOSPrinterPingLog.txt"
$offlineprinters = "D:\Reports\MPOS\MPOSOfflinePrinters.txt"
if (Test-Path $logfile) {Remove-Item $logfile}
if (Test-Path $offlineprinters) {Remove-Item $offlineprinters}

Add-Content $logfile "Setting local path"
$localPath = "C:\Temp\MPOS"

Add-Content $logfile "Gathering server list"
$serverList = (Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like 'Q0*P30' -or Name -like 'Q0*P32'" -SearchBase "OU=Print,OU=Prod,OU=POS,DC=COMPANY,DC=NET").name | Sort-Object | Out-File C:\Temp\MPOS\MPOSPrintServers.txt
$serverListPath = "C:\Temp\MPOS\MPOSPrintServers.txt"

#Retrieve a list of MPOS Print servers from text file and set to $serverNames
Add-Content $logfile "Compiling text file"
$serverNames = Get-Content -Path $serverListPath

#Iterate through each of the server names
foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {
    Add-Content $logfile "Processing $serverName" 

    #Check if the server is online before doing the remote command
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $serverName -Quiet -count 1) {
        Add-Content $logfile "$serverName is online"

        #copy config file from MPOS print to local server for processing
        $timestamp1 = (Get-Date -Format g)
        Add-Content $logfile "$timestamp1 - Copying xml file from server to local path"
        $configPath = "\\$($serverName)\C$\ProgramData\Microsoft\Point Of Service\Configuration\Configuration.xml"
        Copy-Item $configPath $localPath 

        #process xml file to parse IP addresses for ping
        $timestamp2 = (Get-Date -Format g)
        Add-Content $logfile "$timestamp2 - Processing xml file from $serverName to parse data to csv"
        $xml = [xml](Get-Content C:\Temp\MPOS\Configuration.xml)
        $PrinterNames = $xml.selectNodes('//PointOfServiceConfig/ServiceObject/Device') | foreach {New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{LogicalName=$_.LogicalName.Name}}
        $PrinterIPs = $xml.selectNodes('//PointOfServiceConfig/ServiceObject/Device') | foreach {New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{HardwarePath=$_.HardwarePath}} 

        foreach ($PrinterIP in $PrinterIPs) {
            $pingableIP = $PrinterIP.HardwarePath

            if (Test-Connection $pingableIP -Quiet -Count 1) {
                $timestamp3 = (Get-Date -Format g)
                Add-Content $logfile "$timestamp3 - $serverName, $pingableIP is online and pingable"
            } else {
                $timestamp3 = (Get-Date -Format g)
                Add-Content $offlineprinters "$timestamp3 - $serverName, $pingableIP is offline!"
            }
        }
    } else {
        Add-Content $logfile "$serverName is offline!"
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the part that is taking the longest? AD query or the pings?

Comment: How many devices? `Test-Connection` is synchronous and doesn't let you control the timeout.

Comment: I suggest you put a few echo's in at places that may be causing the problem, see how many times it's iterating through the loop for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I believe that you are facing issues due to pings, I don't think the AD query takes most of the time, so what you should do - is parallel the pings. [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) would be the great place to start.

```
foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {
    start-rsjob -Name $_ -ScriptBlock {
        # your code in the loop goes here #
        }
}            
Get-RSjob | Receive-RSJob
```

or you could just write your own runspace wrapper ;)
in case you are interested, I had a script parsing text files, it was taking like 6-7 minutes to complete, after I implemented runspaces to parallel stuff it started completing in 5 milliseconds . how crazy is that? xD

Comment: I think this is the issue as well, and PoshRSJob is a great module.

Comment: I will try this, thank you very much for your assistance and your kindness!